# In Java, how can I access an ArrayList of integer arrays

Tags: java, android

Here's my code:

```
    // create an arraylist of type integer array
    ArrayList<int[]> timesTables = new ArrayList<>();

    // add data
    timesTables.add(new int[]{42, 17, 81});
    timesTables.add(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
    timesTables.add(new int[]{1000, 2000, 3000});

    // this does not work        
    Log.i("Status ", timesTables.get((0)[0]).toString());
```

I know the mistake here has something to do with the way I'm attempting to reference the data with (0)[0], but I can't figure out the correct syntax. I know that this works:

```
    Log.i("Status ", timesTables.get(0).toString());
```

But this only gives the array address (I think) and not the values of an array nor an individual value in one array, which is what I'm attempting.

Secondary question: I attempted to look at the documentation to answer this question myself, but as a beginner, I was unsure where to look. I didn't know which website I should be using or which piece of code I should be looking up (get, int[], etc..).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You would need get(0)[0]. The method call returns an array object, then you use the square bracket to specify an index.

Comment: And note that mixing generics and arrays is bad practice. Normally you either use only arrays or only collections. Mixing those two concepts isn't something you do often in the real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are creating is a **list** of **int primitive arrays**.

So, use the List's **get()** method to obtain by index which array to use, followed by the index of the target entry in the obtained array.

```
timesTables.get(0)[0]
```

You can't use **toString** as the value you wish to print is an **int primitive type**.

So for your specific question you can do as next:

```
 Log.i("Status", Integer.toString(timesTables.get(0)[0]));
```

To clarify a bit your doubts, in a more verbose way, the above is the same as doing next:

```
 int[] array = timesTables.get(0); // Get by index an array from the list
 int value = array[0]; // Get by index an int value from the obtained array
 Log.i("Status", Integer.toString(value));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't put an index of nothing, so you should write the name of the array you're trying to access when you write `(0)`.

```
// create an arraylist of type integer array
    ArrayList<int[]> timesTables = new ArrayList<>();

    // add data
    timesTables.add(new int[]{42, 17, 81});
    timesTables.add(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
    timesTables.add(new int[]{1000, 2000, 3000});

    // this does not work        
    Log.i("Status ", Integer.toString(timesTables.get(0)[0]));
```

Comment: This doesnt work. You get an array of int, then you pick an entry... Which is of type int. int does not have a toString method!

Comment: True, just have to edit the ````toString```` method.

Comment: Pointless. You don't need that extra call in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct in that this prints the object reference of the int array.

```
Log.i("Status ", timesTables.get(0).toString());
```

If you want to print the contents of the array instead, use [Arrays.toString(...)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-tostring-in-java-with-examples/), e.g.:

```
Log.i("Status ", Arrays.toString(timesTables.get(0)));
```